# numpy invert stride selection

Tags: numpy, set, slice, selection

Consider the following code:

```
aa = np.arange(16)
step = 4
bb = aa[::4]
```

This selects every 4th element. Is there a quick and easy numpy function to select the complement of `bb`?  I'm looking for the following output

```
array([1,  2,  3, 5,  6,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15])
```

Yes, I could generate indices and then do `np.setdiff1d`, but I'm looking for something more elegant than that.

Comment: Start with a boolean mask of all True.  Use [::4] to set some elements to False.  Or use `np.delete` to do that for you. Or reshspe `aa` to (4,4) and select 3 columnd.

Comment: The basic point of all these suggestions, including your method, is that it isn't as simple as the '::4' slice.  The result will be a copy, not a view.  Most of the suggestions use some form of advanced indexing, either with boolean or integer array.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple single-liner:

```
np.delete(aa,slice(None,None,4))
```

Another solution (I don't know about elegant), but you could define a selection index of ones, and then set every fourth element to False to then index the original array:

```
o = np.ones_like(s,dtype=bool)
o[::step] = False 
aa[o]
```

Answer (score 1):

A flexible way to select based on an arbitrary repeated position could be to use a modulo:

```
bb = aa[np.arange(len(aa))%step != step-1]
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14])
```